Error playing an audio stream using Expo AV in React Native
Using the Expo-AV library in React Native, I have trouble reading an audio stream from a flask server.
The problem only occurs in iOS (AVPlayer) sometimes but not always, no problem at all with Android.
Here's the code to stream in Flask :
def stream_speech_audio(speech_id: str):

    # ~ Stream the audio
    def generator():
        speech = get_speech_audio(speech_id)
        with speech as s:
            for chunk in s.iter_bytes(1024):
                if chunk:
                    yield chunk
                else:
                    break
        yield b""

    return Response(
        generator(),
        mimetype="audio/aac",
        headers={
            "Content-Type": "audio/aac",
            "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
            "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        },
    )

When the problem occurs on iOS which is sometimes, and almost never in development mode, I have this error in flask :
File "/app/blueprints/chats_vision_blueprint.py", line 477, in generator
for chunk in s.iter_bytes(1024):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/_response.py", line 354, in iter_bytes
for chunk in self.http_response.iter_bytes(chunk_size):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_models.py", line 831, in iter_bytes
for raw_bytes in self.iter_raw():
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_models.py", line 885, in iter_raw
for raw_stream_bytes in self.stream:
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 127, in __iter__
for chunk in self._stream:
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 115, in __iter__
with map_httpcore_exceptions():
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 89, in map_httpcore_exceptions
raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.RemoteProtocolError: peer closed connection without sending complete message body (incomplete chunked read)
Truncated response body. Usually implies that the request timed out or the application exited before the response was finished.

The error in the app is something of : "AVPlayer Error: Seeking interrupted".
And the code to read the audio is the usual Expo docs demo :
 await Audio.Sound.createAsync({ uri: responseSpeechURL })

Oh fellow devs, does anyone have a solution ?
